# JavaScript works on Localhost, but not on live site

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to create a small JS clicking game, where a random image from a folder spawns and the user clicks it. My code is working fine on Localhost, but when i moved it all to a live site, I get a 404 undefined error.

Here is my code:

I've been trying to solve this fora day now, can't get it to work properly. Also I know the CSS should be in an external file, and it will be eventually. :)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Naamari_peli</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                font-family: sans-serif;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                width: 100%;
            }

            #shape {
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                background-position: center;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                display: none;
                position: relative;
                background-size: 100%;
            }

            .bold {
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            #top{
                width: 90%;
                margin:0 auto;
                text-align: center;
            }

            #gameArea {
                margin: auto;
                height: 80%;
                width: 90%;
                border-radius:8%;
                border: 3px groove grey;
                position: relative;
                background-image: url(backgrounds/kai.jpeg);
                background-size: cover;
                background-position: top;

            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="top">
            <h1>Naamapeli</h1>

            <p></p>

            <p class="bold">Aika: <span id="timeTaken"></span></p>
        </div>
        <div id="gameArea">
            <div id="shape"></div>
        </div>

        <script type=text/javascript">
            var imgArray = [
            <?php
            $post_dir = "/";
            $images = glob($post_dir . "*.jpg");
            $listImages=array();
            foreach($images as $image){
                echo "'$image',\n";
            }
            ?>
            ];
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var start = new Date().getTime();

            /* tää lista printataan PHP:lla sivupohjaan
            var imgArray = <?php echo json_encode($listImages); ?>; */

            var imgArray = [
                <?php
                $post_dir = "/";
                $images = glob($post_dir . "*.jpg");
                $listImages=array();
                foreach($images as $image){
                    echo "'$image',\n";
                }
                ?>
            ];

            function makeImgAppear() {
                var rand = imgArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArray.length)];
                var urlString = 'url(' + rand;
                var top = Math.random() * 400;
                var left = Math.random() * 1100;
                var width = (Math.random() * 150) + 75;

                document.getElementById("shape").style.borderRadius = "50%";
                document.getElementById("shape").style.backgroundImage = urlString;
                document.getElementById("shape").style.width = width + "px";
                document.getElementById("shape").style.height = width + "px";
                document.getElementById("shape").style.top = top + "px";
                document.getElementById("shape").style.left = left + "px";
                document.getElementById("shape").style.marginBottom = 0.5 * width + "px";
                document.getElementById("shape").style.position = "relative";
                document.getElementById("shape").style.display = "block";
                start = new Date().getTime();
            }

            function appearAfterDelay() {
                setTimeout(makeImgAppear, Math.random() * 2000);
            }
            appearAfterDelay();

            document.getElementById("shape").onclick = function() {
                document.getElementById("shape").style.display = "none";
                var end = new Date().getTime();
                var timeTaken = (end - start) / 1000;
                document.getElementById("timeTaken").innerHTML = timeTaken + "s";
                appearAfterDelay();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you upload the image  folder? also close the `'url('` string

Comment: Is this a copy/paster of your real code? You're missing a quote on the first script tag: `<script type=text/javascript">`

Comment: The use of PHP within the script tags is wrong. That isn't allowed. PHP is a server side language. You cannot run PHP on the client side.

Comment: check the image url and see why it's not there

Comment: What is URL of your test? I can find an answer better by checking and testing it.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Added these, still doesn't work tho. :/ And yes, the image folders are uploaded too.

Comment: @SimoPiitulainen open the page and go to network tab in the console then you can see the images path.so you can understand why images are not found in that path.

Comment: http://www.teampenor.fi/peli.php Here's the url. I know PHP is server side and js is client side, but that is the only way i found out how to use a array created in PHP in javascript. And it still works just fine on localhost.

Comment: @SimoPiitulainen view source there is nothing in `imgArray` array.and i don't know why you put same javascript code twice.check your php loop.do some tests

Comment: I had the JS containing PHP in it's own script tags, so I forgot to remove it when i moved it within the tags with the rest of the JS. Hence twice the same code. The imgArray is empty, but why could that be? When running on localhost, the PHP creates the imgArray from the images. I can't figure out why isn't it doing the same on the live site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path you are passing to the glob() function is probably causing the problem. I guess your image files are located in the same folder as your php script. So your directory structure will look something like that:

```
htdocs
 peli.php
 kai.jpg
 someimg.jpg
```

If you want to access one of the files in the same folder there is no need for a leading slash.

Use the following

```
 // path without leading slash
 $images = glob("*.jpg");
```

or you can use a relative path just like that

```
// relative path
$images = glob("./*.jpg");
```

both will work fine.

The likeliest reason that it works on your localhost and not on your live site is that there is running a different os than on your local machine. On unix machines, absolute paths start with a slash, e.g.

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

If you now specify

```
/*.jpg
```

as input parameter for the glob() function it will probably look for the jpg files in the root directory, depending on the os your webserver is running on.

If changing the path isn't working and the error remains, take a look at the docs for the glob() function on http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php. The function might not be available on the os your webserver is running on.

> Note: This function isn't available on some systems (e.g. old Sun OS).

Or there is some other error with glob() and the error is not indicated correctly according to the docs.

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns an array containing the matched files/directories, an empty array if no file matched or FALSE on error.
>
> Note: On some systems it is impossible to distinguish between empty
> match and an error.

You can also take a look at the libc.a reference at http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/libc/libc_426.html as the glob() function in php implements the libc glob() pattern matching.

Greets,
Max